# I have to find this Taylor series for function ...

Tags: calculus, functions, taylor-expansion

I'm helping a litle bit to my neighbour with "Calculus 1" and he sent me this exercise, which I sometimes remembered what trick you have to get, but now I forget a little bit.

So, we have function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f(x) = (x^2 + 3x + 1)\cdot e^{2x-1}$, which we have to find the Taylor series at $x = -1$. So please use the $\Sigma$ notation.

I remember just: $e^{2x-1} = e^{2(x+1)-3}$, but know I stacked with $x^2 + 3x + 1$ ... Please help :) It's for my neighbour that I will show him answer ...

Comment: Why pretend like you know the answer with your friend? Also do you know the Taylor expansion for $e^x$? You just would term multiply the polynomial by the Taylor expansion, if you do.

Comment: @Zach466920 It's slightly harder than just multiplying the polynomial by the Taylor expansion (one should put the polynomial in terms of $(x+1)$)

Comment: I think you have issues with writing $f(x)$ in terms of $t=x+1$. Just make the substitution $x=(x+1)-1=t-1$, expand in $t$, and substitute it back when you have the series in $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe:
$$
(x^2+3x+1)e^{2x-1}=(x+1)^2e^{2(x+1)}e^{-3}+(x+1)e^{2(x+1)}e^{-3}-e^{2(x+1)}e^{-3}.
$$

Now, you have
$$
e^{-3}(x+1)^2\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{2^i}{i!}(x+1)^i+e^{-3}(x+1)\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{2^i}{i!}(x+1)^i-e^{-3}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{2^i}{i!}(x+1)^i.
$$

Next, we can simplify by bringing the $(x+1)$ factors inside to get (after reindexing)
$$
\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{e^{-3}2^{i-2}}{(i-2)!}(x+1)^i+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-3}2^{i-1}}{(i-1)!}(x+1)^i+\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{-e^{-3}2^i}{i!}(x+1)^i.
$$

Comment: Thank you for that ... Tommorow I'll show my neighbour ...